# Array Hash algorithm better than Arrays.deepHashCode in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, hash

I feel the algorithm of default Java Arrays.deepHashCode is problematic:

I tried the following code:

```
Integer[] a1 = { 2, 1 };
Integer[] a2 = { 1, 32 };
System.out.println("deepHash a1:" + Arrays.deepHashCode(a1) + " a2:" + Arrays.deepHashCode(a2));
```

The output was:

```
deepHash a1:1024 a2:1024
```

I found in my application that Arrays.deepHashCode will produce lots of clash when the first element of a two element array is small (e.g. 1 or 2).

Does anyone know a better Array hash algorithm? I mean in generally better than Arrays.deepHashCode.

The array could have elements of any type. integer, String, Double, boolean, etc.... Not only Integer. The array could have any number of elements. I need a function to replace Arrays.deepHashCode(Object[]), taking the same type of parameters (Object[]) and giving the same type of output (int).

Comment: Array of integers? You can just use about any hash algorithm out there, for example MurmurHash3

Comment: hash = primeNumber * hash + currentElement.hashCode();

Comment: This hash result is used as the key in a HashMap. It has to be an int. So I can not use those advanced Hash algorithm like SHA.

Comment: This array could have elements of any type. integer, String, Double, boolean, etc.... Not only Integer.

Comment: hoaz: Prime modulus and randomness, please, otherwise it's too easy to break :)

Comment: @Leo Almost all hash algorithms output an integer, including the one I mentioned

Comment: @hoaz Can u show me how to implement your hash algorithm on a multiple-dimension array? hash = primeNumber * hash + currentElement.hashCode();

Comment: @Leo: That is not my hash algorithm. I don't know why you think that

Comment: @NiklasB. Sorry. My mistake.

Comment: @Leo You just iterate over all elements in your array, or multiple-dimension array and calculate hash

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to double the array and then hash.

```
Integer[] a1 = { 2, 1, 2, 1 };
Integer[] a2 = { 1, 32, 1,32 };
```

will not cause conflicts. You can use System.arraycopy() to automatically do the copy.